# How to let user create folder and upload file, lamp permission

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, php, permissions

I use `mkdir($folder_path, 0755)` in localhost(MAMP) it works, but after I move to VPS I use LAMP it failed.

**Folder**
the direction path is  `/var/www/html/assets/images/` the images folder info:
Owner: root
Group: root
Octal: 755
folder`var`, `www`, `html`, `assets` both same

**phpinfo**

**apache2handler**
Apache Version  Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Server Administrator    root@localhost
User/Group  apache(48)/48

**Core**
safe_mode   Local Value Off Master Value Off

I try to let user through upload file and create folder through  below function
`$folder_path = '/var/www/html/backstage/assets/images/0'; 
 if ( mkdir($folder_path, 0755) ) {  ...move_uploaded_file();}`

How to solve it?

(Should I change anything about permission on linux use command line?)
Any suggestion will be appreciated, this is my first time build server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your permission set is incorrect. Assuming all the `/var/www/html` is used by and for apache, you need to change it so it's owned by apache.

```
sudo chown apache:apache -R /var/www/html
```

That will make html folder and everything under it owned by apache and with group as apache.

Also, I would recommend to take time to read up on what Owner/Group/Other and their permissions mean. As your usage of root:root shows lack of core mechanics of Linux OS. Here is one such article: http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Comment: Thanks it works!!  so should I add a user administrator /var/www/html/ , and let him upload folder  and also set php user as him?

Comment: Simplest way is to add the administrator's user to the group. And add group's write permission. `chmod g+w -R /path/to/folder`

Answer (score 0):

you have to check which user runs apache. This should *never* be root! Normally its apache, nobody or www-data. when you know, which user runs apache, you have to change permissions that this specific user can read (and execute and/or write, if needed) the files.

Then it probably will run like in your localhost enviroment

Comment: I said in question...   User apache  Group apache